# How to remove time from date in JavaScript pulling record from SQL

Tags: javascript, sql

```
@Html.Raw(Helper.FormatData("Sale Date: ",
       headerData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sale_Date"].ToString().Trim(), 
       null, true))
```

This is the code that pulls record from SQL. The data was updated and the Sale_ Date column data type was changed. 
now I get the result as `02/01/1999 12.00.00 AM` I would like it to display as `02/01/1999`.

Is there any JavaScript code that convert this code?

Comment: The moment.js library has numerous date display capabilities and can do this.

Comment: when I use ToString ("d") I get the following error

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: `((DateTime)headerData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sale_Date"]).ToString("d")`

Comment: Thank you this worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.Raw(Helper.FormatData("Sale Date: ",
((DateTime)headerData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sale_Date"]).ToString("d"),
     null, true))
```

Comment: this is the error I get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Substring' and no extension method 'Substring' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)